# How to write a Query to get the Hierarchical flow

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two tables like Account and Grouptxt for each record in Accounts table i need to find the dependencies in Grouptxt Table,below is the sample data of those 2 tables

Account Table Data:-

## AccountName,ShortName,Type,OpBal,ParentGroup,Move4Report,DebitLimit,CreditLimit

'C' Mannto,'C' Mannto,Customer/Supplier,0.0,Debtors Belgaum,True,0.0,0.0

2M Engineers,2M Engineers,Customer/Supplier,260.0,Debtors Belgaum,True,0.0,0.0

A. A. Engineering,A. A. Engineering,Customer/Supplier,114.0,Debtors Belgaum,False,0.0,0.0

A.C. Enterprises,A.C. Enterprises,Customer/Supplier,0.0,Creditors forMaterials,True,0.0,0.0

Grouptxt Table Data:-

## GroupName,ShortName,ParentGroup,isSystem,IsTradingGroup

Asset, Asset, ,True,False

APPLICATION OF FUNDS,APPLICATION OF FUNDS,Asset,False,False

Fixed Assets,Fixed Assets,APPLICATION OF FUNDS,False,False

Gross Block,Gross Block,Fixed Assets,False,False

---

So now my Question is for each record in Account tables i need to get the dependencies from grouptxt table.How to do that?

the O/P Should be in this format
Expenditure <-- Materials Consumed <--Raw Material & Components  A.C. Enterprises,A.C. Enterprises,Customer/Supplier,0.0,Creditors for Materials,True,0.0,0.0

For the Record A.C.Enterprises the Dependencies are Raw Material & Components --> Materials Consumed --> Expenditure

like this i need to get for entire table,but not getting how to do that for the entire table

I Tried like this

SELECT #AccountName
      ,a.ShortName
      ,a.Type
      ,a.OpBal
      ,a.ParentGroup
      ,a.Move4Report
      ,a.DebitLimit
      ,a.CreditLimit
      ,a.row_id,
      g.ParentGroup AS GrpTxt_ParentGroup
FROM Grouptxt   g inner join account a
ON a.ParentGroup=g.ShortName
WHERE #AccountName='Increase/Decrease In Finished Goods'

SELECT * FROM Grouptxt where ParentGroup='Raw Material & Components'

SELECT * FROM Grouptxt Where ShortName='Raw Material & Components'

SELECT * FROM Grouptxt Where ShortName='Materials Consumed'

SELECT * FROM Grouptxt Where ShortName='Expenditure'

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you put this into a SQL Fiddle and show us what's wrong?

Comment: Can you, please, explain more carefully the needed purpose cant eh existing data set. From your example in't hard to understand how do the "Expenditure" related to the date and so on...

Comment: On a sidenote, please try to reformat your question using Stackoverflow's code block option. It will make your question more clear and would help us to give the answer quickly.